# Can't explain poor bandwidth performance using boost asio TCP sockets

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, boost-asio

The following is an example I wrote of a trivial TCP server and matching client to start practicing boost's asio library, [Example TCP Client/Server](https://gist.github.com/o-zombi-o/9f3c12ac25d981de7f41a3273af3bedf).

- The client simply connects and sends data as fast as it can from a memory buffer.
- The server solely listens for messages and prints how many bytes it got from a complete message.

That's it - nothing more. Booth examples run on a few threads, mostly default settings are used, there's no haphazardly placed sleeps that might be throwing things off... They're really fairly straightforward to follow, there's practically nothing other than a direct call to boost with the goal of isolating the problem.

The thing is, that the client's output is the following:

**Mbytes/sec: 51.648908, Gbytes/sec: 0.051649, Mbits/sec: 413.191267, Gbits/sec: 0.413191**

Notes:

- I'm running my laptop off battery power right now. If I plug it into a power jack it'll jump to ~0.7 Gbits/sec.
- I've tried sending small 2048 byte messages to the current 8 Mbyte messages.
- I've tried with the nagle algorithm enabled and disabled.
- I've tried resizing send and receive OS buffers.
- All of this is running via loopback, `127.0.0.1`.
- Monitoring loopback via Wireshark shows the same low bandwidth usage.

The actual point that prompted me to write the question is this one. The [iperf tool](https://iperf.fr/) is able to achieve **33.0 Gbits/sec** using TCP via localhost.

```
$ iperf --client 127.0.0.1
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 127.0.0.1, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 2.50 MByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 127.0.0.1 port 41952 connected with 127.0.0.1 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  38.4 GBytes  33.0 Gbits/sec
```

All searches for something along the lines of "TCP boost asio performance" tend to wind up with suggestions to disable nagle or adjusting OS socket buffers.

If anyone could point me in the right direction to understand why I'm obtaining such low bandwidth performance using boost asio I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I got it up to 3GBps by just commenting out all the socket receive and send buffer size options and deferring the needed resizing to TCP auto tuning. Also I changed the server receive code to not do an iteration over the buffer, that is a waste. My changed code at http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UUlmqwH5tlD4Ah4f

Comment: It would be better to see what iperf is doing. May be it is using some zero copy mechanism to just send ?

Comment: Oh..I did not see it was 33G'bits' per sec in iperf. Then with my changes it is 24Gbits per sec :). Close enough but I am sure much can be done. Rerunning it again showed something around 30 Gbps this time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all let me point out the things you are doing wrong for this kind of test.

1. Manual setting of TCP buffer size

This is better left for the TCP algorithm to figure out what is the best size. This is usually determined during the TCP `slow-start` phase where the TCP algorithm finally decides on a best possible `window-size` based upon the congestion. Since we are using local host and that too point to point connection without any in between network components, the congestion would be near zero.

2. Enabling Nagles algorithm

This is not actually needed since you are not sending framed packets of short length. It is usually then when turning on Nagles would give you some benefit on `latency` (for throughput I am not so sure if there would be any improvement).

3. Unwanted processing on server side

I see that you are iterating over the received buffer and doing some kind of meaningless check. `iperf` for sure does not do that. I have commented out that section of code.

4. Receiving application buffer size

I don't know but for some reason you have chosen to read only `2048` bytes per receive. Any particular reason for that? I have changed it back to the actual size that was being written by the client. You were probably just queueing more data on the server receive section.

New Server code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <signal.h>
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <system_error>

namespace
{
bool keepGoing = true;
void shutdown(int)
{
        keepGoing = false;
}

std::size_t bytesAccum = 0;
void justReceive(std::error_code ec, std::size_t bytesReceived,
    asio::ip::tcp::socket &socket, std::vector<unsigned char> &buffer)
{
        bytesAccum += bytesReceived;
/*
        auto end = buffer.begin() + bytesReceived;
        for (auto it = buffer.begin(); it != end; ++it)
        {
                if (*it == 'e')
                {
                        std::printf("server got: %lu\n", bytesAccum);
                        bytesAccum = 0;
                }
        }
*/
        socket.async_receive(
            asio::buffer(buffer),
            0,
            [&] (auto ec, auto bytes) {
              justReceive(ec, bytes, socket, buffer);
            });
}
}

int main(int, char **)
{
        signal(SIGINT, shutdown);

        asio::io_service io;
        asio::io_service::work work(io);

        std::thread t1([&]() { io.run(); });
        std::thread t2([&]() { io.run(); });
        std::thread t3([&]() { io.run(); });
        std::thread t4([&]() { io.run(); });

        asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io,
            asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(
                asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 1234));
        asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io);

        // accept 1 client
        std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(131072, 0);
        acceptor.async_accept(socket, [&socket, &buffer](std::error_code ec)
        {
            // options
            //socket.set_option(asio::ip::tcp::no_delay(true)); 
            //socket.set_option(asio::socket_base::receive_buffer_size(8192  * 2));
            //socket.set_option(asio::socket_base::send_buffer_size(8192));

            socket.async_receive(
                asio::buffer(buffer),
                0,
                [&](auto ec, auto bytes) {
                  justReceive(ec, bytes, socket, buffer);
                });
        });

        while (keepGoing)
        {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }

        io.stop();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
        t4.join();

        std::printf("server: goodbye\n");
}
```

New client code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <signal.h>
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <system_error>

namespace
{
bool keepGoing = true;
void shutdown(int) { keepGoing = false; }
}

int main(int, char **)
{
        signal(SIGINT, shutdown);

        asio::io_service io;
        asio::io_service::work work(io);

        std::thread t1([&]() { io.run(); });
        std::thread t2([&]() { io.run(); });
        std::thread t3([&]() { io.run(); });
        std::thread t4([&]() { io.run(); });

        asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io);
        auto endpoint = asio::ip::tcp::resolver(io).resolve({ 
            "127.0.0.1", "1234" });
        asio::connect(socket, endpoint);

        // options to test
        //socket.set_option(asio::ip::tcp::no_delay(true)); 
        //socket.set_option(asio::socket_base::receive_buffer_size(8192));
        //socket.set_option(asio::socket_base::send_buffer_size(8192 * 2));

        std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(131072, 0);
        buffer.back() = 'e';

        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> last = 
            std::chrono::system_clock::now();

        std::chrono::duration<double> delta = std::chrono::seconds(0);

        std::size_t bytesSent = 0;

        while (keepGoing)
        {
                // blocks during send
                asio::write(socket, asio::buffer(buffer));
                //socket.send(asio::buffer(buffer));

                // accumulate bytes sent
                bytesSent += buffer.size();

                // accumulate time spent sending
                delta += std::chrono::system_clock::now() - last;
                last = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

                // print information periodically
                if (delta.count() >= 5.0) 
                {
                        std::printf("Mbytes/sec: %f, Gbytes/sec: %f, Mbits/sec: %f, Gbits/sec: %f\n",
                                    bytesSent / 1.0e6 / delta.count(),
                                    bytesSent / 1.0e9 / delta.count(),
                                    8 * bytesSent / 1.0e6 / delta.count(),
                                    8 * bytesSent / 1.0e9 / delta.count());

                        // reset accumulators
                        bytesSent = 0;
                        delta = std::chrono::seconds(0);
                }
        }

        io.stop();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
        t4.join();

        std::printf("client: goodbyte\n");
}
```

NOTE: I used standalone version of `asio`, but the results as reported by the OP were reproducible on my machine which is :

MacBook Pro Yosemite - 2.6 GHz Intel Core i5 Processor - 8GB DDR3 RAM
.

Comment: Thank you for your observations! I mixed up my files when uploading my examples but I had also tried default boost::asio settings (without messing with nagle or OS socket buffer sizes). What I hadn't tried was your **4th point**. This, specifically was the bottleneck in my example! Boost was simply doing too much work with such a small inbound buffer on the server side. Enlarging it gets me up to 40 Gbits/sec on my i5 8Gb RAM Linux system. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Arunmu What is `slow-start` phase?